# How to implement dynamic vector tile sever

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles

In my application, the backend (written in Java using spring boot) is serving REST API which expose a service that returns thousands of coordinates (based on filters it gets from the client). My frontend is using this API and then displays the results in Mapbox map.

The performance is not good enough for 100K of points and more, and we want to use vector tiles instead.

Since the data is dynamic, we would want our backend to act as a vector tile server, is this possible?

What's needed in order to server vector tile requests? Is there a library that can help?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. It's pretty straightforward to accept a request for a vector tile, then generate that tile and serve it back. It gets a little bit more complex when you factor in caching for performance, and trying to avoid redundant work.

I'm mostly familiar with JavaScript libraries, but [mapbox-vector-tile-java](https://github.com/wdtinc/mapbox-vector-tile-java) looks like it will handle the part of turning geometry into a Mapbox vector tile.

Comment: Thanks @steve, this is helpful for the encoding part, I still don't know how to implement the API itself. As there are several API endpoints I should implement, but I couldn't find instructions/documentation for what exactly is needed.

Comment: No, there really aren't. You just an endpoint which provides `/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf` or however you define the tile endpoint. You can create a [tileJSON](https://github.com/mapbox/tilejson-spec) endpoint for extra credit.

Comment: You can see this (Javascript) example to see what I mean: there's only one endpoint that matters. https://glitch.com/edit/#!/procmap?path=server.js%3A57%3A0

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

[youtube video for dynmic vector tile platform](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dmH2jFdewo)

> 1.No Need for Pre-cutting or Caching:
> Whether it's vector tiles or raster tiles, there's no need to pre-generate them. Data is displayed as it changes, greatly reducing the tile maintenance workload.
> 2.Distributed Support:
> Support for building distributed deployments across multiple nodes to accelerate frontend performance.
> 3.Cache Strategy Support:
> Various caching strategies are available, including hierarchical caching (e.g., caching map levels below 12), dynamic regional caching (ensuring specific area ranges remain dynamic), and scheduled cache refresh for data (e.g., refreshing level caches during the night).
> 4.Dynamic CAD Data Publishing:
> Support for dynamic uploading of CAD files and immediate publishing. Depending on file size, a 3-megabyte file takes approximately 5 seconds to publish.
> 5.Data Source Support:
> Compatible with SuperMap, Shapefile, GeoPackage, PostGIS, and TIFF data formats.
> 6.Dynamic Vector Tile Projection:
> No need for data coordinate transformation for original data; dynamic projection is supported.